# Quarto book won't reder to pdf after adding image (html works): Error running filter /opt/quarto/share/filters/quarto-init/quarto-init.lua

Tags: pdf, lua, rstudio, quarto

I am using quarto book in Rstudio. Rendering to pdf used to work but now that I have added an image it stopped working with the following error (Rendering to html still works perfectly):

```
Error running filter /opt/quarto/share/filters/quarto-init/quarto-init.lua:
/opt/quarto/share/filters/quarto-init/quarto-init.lua:246: attempt to index a nil value (global 'text')
stack traceback:
    /opt/quarto/share/filters/quarto-init/quarto-init.lua:16: in local 'fn'
    /opt/quarto/share/filters/quarto-init/quarto-init.lua:554: in function </opt/quarto/share/filters/quarto-init/quarto-init.lua:548>
```

Has someone encountered this before and knows what to do?

I have updated to the latest quarto **(1.0.38)** and Rstudio but the error still persists.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.
The image path had an extra \ eg. \images\img1.png.
Once changed to images\img1.png. it worked fine